# angular ssr mod.require is not a function

Tags: server-side-rendering, angular9

I'm developing an angular ssr application. When I do `npm run dev:ssr` I'm getting the following error

```
Your NodeJS application doesn't support 'perf_hooks'. TypeError: mod.require is not a function 
A server error has occurred.
node exited with 1 code.
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:54208
```

I don't know what is causing me this error? Can some one help me to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [ngx-skeleton-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-skeleton-loader)?
All versions > 2.2.1 are using perf_hooks through the [perf-marks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/perf-marks) package.

I reverted to 2.2.1. And will try to find a different solution for loader-skeletons.

Comment: Yes i'm using but version is 2.2.0

Comment: Are you sure? Do you have have a wildcard in the package.json?